# Scrollbars disappear when try to overload paintEvent function

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, qpixmap, qscrollarea

I have a `QLabel` in a `QScrollArea`. When I set the label's pixmap with the `setPixmap` function, the scrollbars appear to cover entire image. But when I try to overload the `paintEvnet` function and draw an image with `QPainter::drawImage`, scrollbars disappear and for discovering the entire image I have to resize the the program's window. What is the solution?

Comment: Check if you create a `QPainter` object for `viewport()` widget, not for your `QScrollArea` itself.

Comment: just do QLabel.setMinimumsize(w,h) and QLabel.setMaximumSize(w,h)